# If a user of my site gives me info of a third party they claim to be affiliated with, am I allowed to contact that third party to check?

Tags: privacy, gdpr, data-protection

I am developing an app where a part of the on-boarding process requires users to enter the email / company name of the agency that they are affiliated with (the 3rd party). I need to confirm that they *really are* a member of this 3rd party agency, to prevent fraudulent use of my app.

Am I allowed to use the email / company name they enter, to contact this third party to ask if the user is a member?
If I am, what considerations would I need to make regarding GDPR (Europe) and general data protection?

I would already tell the user that I'd use this info to contact the third party.

Notes: This would be my system automatically contacting this third party, not me, myself.

Cheers

Comment: Asking the third party might be OK if the user is completely aware about what's happening, but what would be the legal basis for that third party to share information about their customers with you? Depending on what kind of agency you're talking about, they would likely mark your automated email as spam.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, there would be no legal basis, i.e. there is nothing compelling the third party to do this other than confirming or denying that they are affiliated with the user.